# SQL - Window function - sum of the amount till the end of prev month / till the end of prev year

Tags: spark-window-function

I have a table with date and amount columns.
I got the 28 days rolling avg like this:

```
AVG(sum_of_amount) OVER (ORDER BY date RANGE BETWEEN INTERVAL 27 DAYS PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS 28_days_roll_avg
```

I would need the same roll_avg from the same period of previous year.

I got the sum_value from the beginning of this year till today like this:

```
SUM(sum_of_amount) OVER (PARTITION BY year(date) ORDER BY date RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS amount_cum_cnt
```

I would need the sum of amount from the beginning of this year till the end of prev month.
I would need the sum of amount from the beginning of previous year till the same day as today of prev year.

Can you help me out?

I just do not know how to specify the time range for previous year.